# How to check if string contains two words in c?

Tags: c, string, validation, input

I want to make a validation in c where the user has to input a string that **must be 2 words**. Initially, I thought of using `strstr(input, " ")`, to check for a space in the input but I figured that the user could put the space at the beginning and the end of the string, and they could also put more than one space resulting in more than 2 words. Does anyone have an easy solution for this? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int input;
    do {
        printf("Enter 2 words: ");
        scanf(%[^\n], input);
        getchar();
    } while (!strstr(input, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One idea I have is to trim the string (remove all spaces from each end), then split the string on the space character, and validate the strings to ensure they are alphabetic, and that there are just two.

Comment: Something like `sscanf(input, "%*s%*s%*s") == 2` maybe (if "word" is defined as a sequence of non-whitespace characters). Unrelated, but use fgets to read lines.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: unfortunately, suppressed conversions are not counted in the return value of `sscanf()`.

Comment: @chqrlie darn... scratch it, then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtok and use space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find a solution for this.

1. the input must only have one space.
2. the space cannot be in the beginning or at the end of the input.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main(){
      char input[50];
      int len, ctr;
      do{
         printf("Enter 2 words: ");
         scanf(%[^\n], input); getchar();
         len = strlen(input);
         ctr = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if(input[i] == ' ') ctr++;
         }
      }while(input[0] == ' ' || ctr != 1 || input[len-1] == ' ');

      return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: instead of `scanf(%[^\n], input); getchar();` you should use `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);`. Your method to compute the number of words is incorrect: there might be more than one space between the words and spaces at the beginning and or at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The following function returns the number of words in a (NULL terminated) string given a delimiter:

```
int word_count(char *str, char delimiter)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (!str || !*str)
        return (0);
    if (*str != delimiter && *(str))
        i = 1;
    while (*(str + 1))
    {
        if (*str == delimiter
            && *(str + 1) != delimiter
            && *(str + 1))
        {
            i++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return (i);
}
```

The logic behind it is it counts words each time the `char` sequence changes from a delimiter to a non `\0` char, starting the number of words at 1 in case the string is not NULL and the first `char` is not a delimiter.
Susbtitute `delimiter` for `' '` and pass your scanned string to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `scanf(%[^\n], input);` has a syntax error and a type mismatch: `input` should be defined as an array of `char`, say `char input[128];` and the syntax is `scanf("%127[^\n]", input);`
- `strstr(input, " ")`, assuming `input` is an array of `char` will find a space in the string, but this is not sufficient to test for 2 words. Counter-examples: `" "`, `" hello"`, `"world "`, `"a b c"`...

It is much more reliable to use `fgets()` to read a full line of input from the user and parse the line with a precise method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[128];
    char word1[128];
    char word2[128];
    char ch;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter 2 words: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            // end of file
            fprintf(stderr, "unexpected end of file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // parse exactly 2 words with optional initial and/or trailing whitespace 
        if (sscanf(buf, "%s%s %c", word1, word2, &ch) == 2)
            break;
        printf("Input must have exactly 2 words.\n");
    }
    printf("word1: %s\nword2: %s\n", word1, word2);
    return 0;
}
```